# apply function to return a data.table, or convert the list directly to a data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, bioconductor, iranges

I would like to apply a function that returns a matrix to each row of a large data.table object (original file is around 30 GB, I have 80 GB ram), and get back a data.table object.  I'd like to do it efficiently.  My current approach is the following:

```
my.function <- function(x){
    alnRanges<-cigarToIRanges(x[6]);
    alnStarts<-start(alnRanges)+as.numeric(x[4])-1;
    alnEnds<-end(alnRanges)+as.numeric(x[4])-1;
    y<-x[-4];
    ys<-matrix(rep(y,length(alnRanges)),nrow=length(alnRanges),ncol=length(y),byrow=TRUE);
    ys<-cbind(ys,alnStarts,alnEnds);
    return(ys);     # ys is a matrix
}

    my.dt<-fread(my.file.name);
    my.list.of.matrices<-apply(my.dt,1,my.function);
    new.df<-do.call(rbind.data.frame,my.list.of.matrices);
    colnames(new.df)[1:14]<-colnames(my.dt)[-4];
    new.dt<-as.data.table(new.df);
```

Note1: I specify the my.function just to show that it returns a matrix, and that my apply line is therefore a list of matrices.

Note2: I am not sure how slow are the operations I am doing but seems that I could reduce the number of lines.  For example, is it slow to convert a data frame to a data table for large objects?

Reproducible example:

Note that Arun and Roland made me think harder about the problem so I am still working on it... may be that I do not need these lines...

I want to take a sam file, and then create a new coordinates file where each read is split according to its CIGAR field.

```
My sam file:
qname   rname   pos cigar
2218    chr1    24613476    42M2S
2067    chr1    87221030    44M
2129    chr1    79702717    44M
2165    chr1    43113438    44M
2086    chr1    52155089    4M921N40M

code:

library("data.table");
library("GenomicRanges");

sam2bed <- function(x){
    alnRanges<-cigarToIRanges(x[4]);
    alnStarts<-start(alnRanges)+as.numeric(x[3])-1;
    alnEnds<-end(alnRanges)+as.numeric(x[3])-1;
    #y<-as.data.frame(x[,pos:=NULL]);
    #ys<-y[rep(seq_len(nrow(y)),length(alnRanges)),];
    y<-x[-3];
    ys<-matrix(rep(y,length(alnRanges)),nrow=length(alnRanges),ncol=length(y),byrow=TRUE);
    ys<-cbind(ys,alnStarts,alnEnds);
    return(ys);
}


sam.chr.dt<-fread(sam.parent.chr.file);
setnames(sam.chr.dt,old=c("V1","V2","V3","V4"),new=c("qname","rname","pos","cigar"));
bed.chr.lom<-apply(sam.chr.dt,1,sam2bed);
> bed.chr.lom
[[1]]
                           alnStarts  alnEnds   
[1,] "2218" "chr1" "42M2S" "24613476" "24613517"

[[2]]
                         alnStarts  alnEnds   
[1,] "2067" "chr1" "44M" "87221030" "87221073"

[[3]]
                         alnStarts  alnEnds   
[1,] "2129" "chr1" "44M" "79702717" "79702760"

[[4]]
                         alnStarts  alnEnds   
[1,] "2165" "chr1" "44M" "43113438" "43113481"

[[5]]
                               alnStarts  alnEnds   
[1,] "2086" "chr1" "4M921N40M" "52155089" "52155092"
[2,] "2086" "chr1" "4M921N40M" "52156014" "52156053"

bed.chr.df<-do.call(rbind.data.frame,bed.chr.lom);

> bed.chr.df
    V1   V2        V3 alnStarts  alnEnds
1 2218 chr1     42M2S  24613476 24613517
2 2067 chr1       44M  87221030 87221073
3 2129 chr1       44M  79702717 79702760
4 2165 chr1       44M  43113438 43113481
5 2086 chr1 4M921N40M  52155089 52155092
6 2086 chr1 4M921N40M  52156014 52156053

bed.chr.dt<-as.data.table(bed.chr.df);

> bed.chr.dt
     V1   V2        V3 alnStarts  alnEnds
1: 2218 chr1     42M2S  24613476 24613517
2: 2067 chr1       44M  87221030 87221073
3: 2129 chr1       44M  79702717 79702760
4: 2165 chr1       44M  43113438 43113481
5: 2086 chr1 4M921N40M  52155089 52155092
6: 2086 chr1 4M921N40M  52156014 52156053
```

Comment: You shouldn't need (and use) `apply` with data.table. The goal should be avoiding copies. Please provide reproducible data and explain what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @Roland, I need to apply a function to each row of the data.table. If I shouldn't use apply then I am not sure what else I could do, I am not familiar with data tables, but I do know they are much faster than data frames.  Trying to produce an example...

Comment: As I said, provide a working example (including data and necessary packages) and tell us what you want to achieve. You won't get the advantages of data.table if you mix it with `apply`.

Comment: I see that you are using iranges. You should be working with bam/Sam files? You should explain what you are trying to do. Because there is no efficient way to using data.table with apply. You just apply your function to every row... And it will be slow or not depending on the number of rows and the time per row.

Comment: @Arun, thanks, you are right, I am using sam/bam files.

Comment: @Roland, thanks, providing example and now putting more explanations...

Comment: I think what you're looking for is this: Assuming your data.table is in `ff`: `cigarToIRangesListByRName(ff$cigar, ff$rname, ff$pos, reduce.ranges = TRUE)`. This should be incredibly fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `ff` is your `data.table`, how about this?

```
splits <- cigarToIRangesListByAlignment(ff$cigar, ff$pos, reduce.ranges = TRUE)
widths <- width(attr(splits, 'partitioning'))
cbind(data.table(qname=rep.int(ff$qname, widths), 
            rname=rep.int(ff$rname, widths)), as.data.frame(splits))

   qname rname space    start      end width
1:  2218  chr1     1 24613476 24613517    42
2:  2067  chr1     2 87221030 87221073    44
3:  2129  chr1     3 79702717 79702760    44
4:  2165  chr1     4 43113438 43113481    44
5:  2086  chr1     5 52155089 52155092     4
6:  2086  chr1     5 52156014 52156053    40
```

Comment: thanks a lot!  great suggestions.  I am also researching on rsamtools, and iranges because maybe I can change all my code to this approach... thanks!